# Why do React component functions lose their properties?

Tags: reactjs

So in the following example, why is `log.added` undefined when you click the button?

```
var log = function(){
  console.log("X");
};

log.added = true;

App = React.createClass({
  log: log,
  showLog(){
    this.log(); // X
    console.log(this.log.added); // undefined
  },
  render(){return (
    <button onClick={this.showLog}>Log</button>
  )}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens whenever a function is rebound, which is what React's createClass function does. Here's the relevant part of the source code if you want to take a look:  https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/src/isomorphic/classic/class/ReactClass.js#L488

However we can reproduce this behaviour easily enough in the console:

```
function x () {}
x.prop = 'foo'
var o = { x: x }
o.x.prop // "foo"
var y = o.x
y.prop // "foo"
var z = o.x.bind(o)
z.prop // undefined <-- rebound prop no longer exists!
```

If you asked because you have a problem in your code, I'm sure there are plenty of workarounds.